# Scala seq of Java self bounded generics

Tags: java, scala, generics

I'm trying to create an array of a bunch of subclasses in scala the issue is the superclass is a self bounded generic i.e. (apparently to accommodate lombok so this isn't something I can change)

```
abstract public SomeClass<T extends SomeClass>{}
```

And in Scala

```
val subClasses:Seq[_ <: SomeClass] = seq(sub1, sub2, ..., subN)
```

The error I get "SomeClass takes type parameters" would seem to indicate that I would need

```
Seq[_ <: SomeClass[_ <: SomeClass[_ <: SomeClass ...
```

After quite a bit of googleing I still haven't found a nice solution and at this point I don't know what to search for. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you paste a minimal example of one of the subclasses? I'm very interested in seeing how this can be concretely instantiated... I think the answer to this may involve `forSome`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The self referencing type is referred to as [F-bounded polymorphism](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded) in scala. To create the Seq you are describing in your example the type would be:

```
Seq[SomeClass[_ >: subN with sub2 with sub1 <: SomeClass[_ >: subN with sub2 with sub1 <: Object]]]
```

Note that this type is specific to the list of items in it, you could create a type that includes all of the subtypes of `SomeClass` but that would get kind of painful.